# VS2015 indentation inside line

Tags: visual-studio, auto-indent

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and develop in C++.
I need VS2015 autoformatting so I can not turn it off, but there is a problem.
I usually write like this:

```
        LPSTR lpszOneLongLine   = NULL;
        DWORD dwShort           = 0;
```

But VS2015 does not like this style and corrects it to:

```
        LPSTR lpszOneLongLine = NULL;
        DWORD dwShort = 0;
```

How can I disable this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this behavior from settings:

Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> C/C++ >> Formatting >> Spacing >> Assignment Operator >> Check Don't change spacing around assignment operators

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped me!